# NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I have the following mappings in 2 of my beans

**Parent Bean**

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "application")
@Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, CascadeType.DELETE})
@JsonIgnore
private Set<ApplicationBuildVO> applicationBuilds = new HashSet<ApplicationBuildVO>(0);
```

**Child Bean**

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Cascade({CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})
@JoinColumn(name = "APPLICATION_ID", nullable = false)
@JsonIgnore
private ApplicationVO application;
```

In my service method - I perform a find on the Application bean
Create a child application bean - which has a reference to the parent application

Then - when I try to update a value on the Parent bean in the same service method I get the following error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.domain.dao.ApplicationVO#1]
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.checkUniqueness(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:617)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:301)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsDetached(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:244)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:109)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
```

My Service code (stripped down) is as follows

```
public boolean performBuild(Integer applicationId) {
        ApplicationVO applicationVO = applicationServices.findAnyApplicationId(applicationId);

        ApplicationBuildVO androidApplicationBuildVO = new ApplicationBuildVO();
        androidApplicationBuildVO.setIsAndroid(true);
        androidApplicationBuildVO.setIsSuccess(appBuildSuccessful);
        androidApplicationBuildVO.setApplication(applicationVO);
        androidApplicationBuildVO.setSoftwareVersion(androidSoftwareVersionVO);
        androidApplicationBuildVO.setS3BucketName(mobileAppsBucketName);
        androidApplicationBuildVO.setS3ArtifactKey(androidArtifact);

        Integer applicationBuildId = applicationBuildServices.saveApplicationBuild(androidApplicationBuildVO);

        applicationVO.setIsCurrentlyBeingBuilt(false);
        boolean updateApplicationResult = applicationServices.updateApplication(applicationVO);          
}
```

Any ideas what I can do to resolve this issue?

Comment: could you post the code of your update?

Comment: Sure - just updated the post

Comment: How are your `@Id`s being assigned?  I assume with some sort of `@GeneratedValue`...

Comment: The ids are autoincremented -     @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id; for both beans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is caused by the fact your are saving `androidApplicationBuildVO` the child first and after that you save the parent `applicationVO` you could add the child to parent and save the parent like that:

```
boolean performBuild(Integer applicationId) {
    ApplicationVO applicationVO = applicationServices.findAnyApplicationId(applicationId);

    ApplicationBuildVO androidApplicationBuildVO = new ApplicationBuildVO();
    androidApplicationBuildVO.setIsAndroid(true);
    androidApplicationBuildVO.setIsSuccess(appBuildSuccessful);
    androidApplicationBuildVO.setApplication(applicationVO);
    androidApplicationBuildVO.setSoftwareVersion(androidSoftwareVersionVO);
    androidApplicationBuildVO.setS3BucketName(mobileAppsBucketName);
    androidApplicationBuildVO.setS3ArtifactKey(androidArtifact);

    applicationVO.addBuild(androidApplicationBuildVO);

    applicationVO.setIsCurrentlyBeingBuilt(false);
    boolean updateApplicationResult = applicationServices.updateApplication(applicationVO);          
     }
```

And you should add this method if it does not exist in `applicationVO`

```
public void addBuild(ApplicationBuildVO buildVo) {
    applicationBuilds.add(buildVo);
}
```

Beware of `equals` and `hashcode` implementations in ApplicationBuildVO not to be based on the id to not have surpises when adding not saved elemnts `applicationBuilds` Set.